# Merging List Alternatively

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

In the following code i am trying to merge 2 list alternatively and than printing them in reverse order. But my code is not giving correct output it is just merging the last element of the second list.
input:

1

3

1 3 5

3

2 4 6

Actual Output: 
5 6 3 1

Expected Output:
5 6 3 4 1 2

Can someone please tell me whats the problem in my code....

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
void push(struct Node ** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
void printList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<' ';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<' ';
}
void mergeList(struct Node **head1, struct Node **head2);

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int n1, n2, tmp;
        struct Node *a = NULL;
        struct Node *b = NULL;
        cin>>n1;
        while(n1--){
            cin>>tmp;
            push(&a, tmp);
        }
        cin>>n2;
        while(n2--){
            cin>>tmp;
            push(&b, tmp);
        }
        mergeList(&a, &b);
        printList(a);
        printList(b);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mergeList(struct Node **p, struct Node **q)
{
     struct Node*temp1=*p,*temp2=*q,*t1,*t2;
     while(temp1!=NULL)
     {
         if(temp2==NULL)
            break;
         t1=temp1->next;
         t2=temp2;
         temp1->next=t2;
         t2->next=t1;
         temp1=t1;
         *q=temp2->next;
         temp2=*q;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain the expected output?

Comment: He's just using *chaining* to populate the list so it just ends up with `1 3 5` and `2 4 6` in reverse order taking one character from each per-iteration.

Comment: If that's the case then should it not be 6 5 4 3 2 1 or 5 6 3 4 1 2?

Comment: Ya i have corrected it

Comment: @AndrewScott Can you please tell me why code is not showing correct output

Comment: Have you thought of using reverse iterator? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/

Comment: Better yet, just keep a *tail_pointer* in addition to your *head_pointer* and you can *forward-chain* adding to the end without having to iterate at all.

Comment: Which is what OP has done in his post

Comment: No, no, no. There is no tail_pointer involved. You have a single head_pointer pointing to the beginning of the list. Nothing points to the last node in the list. That's why the insertion ends up with nodes in reverse order of the input. A tail_pointer simply holds the address of the last node in the list so your insertion is simply `tail->next = new_node; tail = new_node;`. Then your insertions maintain their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm really not sure what exactly you are doing in the `mergeList` function. The code is pretty cancerous so I did not take the liberty of verifying the correctness. I have renamed a few variables and re-written the code, so you can take this as a reference point and see what's wrong with your code.

```
    void mergeList(struct Node **p, struct Node **q)
    {
     struct Node *a = *p, *b = *q, *next_a, *next_b;
     while(a != NULL)
     {
         if(b == NULL)
            break;

         next_a = a->next;
         a->next = b;
         next_b = b->next;
         b->next = next_a;
         a = next_a;
         b = next_b;

     }
 }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: ya i got the idea through your code where i was wrong and hence i corrected my code accordingly.

Comment: Note, since you are merging `b` into `a`, there is no need to pass the address of the pointer. the list-address never changes - you are simply re-wiring pointers. `void mergeList (struct Node *p, struct Node *q)` is fine and eliminates the need for the additional `a` and `b` pointers. (you can iterate with `p` and `q`). Also, `while (a != NULL)` doesn't account for a list where `b` has more nodes. Better `while (a || b) if (!b) break; else if (!a) { a = b; break; } else { /* your code */ }` But, great job with the logic. Worthy of the UV.

Comment: Example of alternative: [MergeList Pointer Re-Wire](http://susepaste.org/83378011) (link expires: Sat May 18 02:46:01 CDT 2019)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions David. Duly noted.